# UITableView borders not show with AccesoryTypeNone

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a Grouped Style table view in my application. When I set the accessoryType to UITableViewCEllAccessoryCheckmark everything is OK, but when i set it as UITableviewAccesoryTypeNone the right border is not shown, as it can be seen in the next image:

[image]

As it can be seen the two firs rows has Checkmark and are seen right, but the other can be seen the round corner that ends de section, and the other ones has not border.

Any suggestion to resolve the problem??

Best Regards.

Comment: maybe you can share the codes for the delegates where you define the table and the cells and create the views of the cells? i have done something similar, and it does not show up like that. :)

Comment: Hi! I have been cheking it and if I disable the right index, the problem dissapears, the border is shown right. Any suggestion?

Comment: please show some code so we can help? :)